# std::getline() is not ending/capturing

Tags: c++, capture, getline

This does not work.

```
playing = true;
while (playing) {
    std::string command;
    std::cin.ignore(1);
    std::getline(std::cin, command);
    execute(command);
    std::cout << "asdasd";
}
```

Whenever the program runs, it does not input whenever I press enter. The cout at the end never fires, and neither does the execute command. So I can keep typing whatever I want, and it never inputs for some reason. I have not used std::cin anywhere in the program.

Comment: it works perfectly fine for me. FYI, I used gcc 4.2.1 to compile under mac. What platform are you using ?

Comment: GCC 4.8 with mac. This code worked perfectly fine an hour ago, and I've tried restarting and everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. In my project, I was using pugixml, and it seems to screw with cin, and makes it not work. I ended up switching to Poco, as it contains a very nice xml library, plus all the networking stuff.